# Github API response copy into a javascript object Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

using the github endpoint https://api.github.com/users/ , i want to copy the json response into a javascript object with the same keys, is there a better way to do it than using oject variable assignment line by line??

the example json response

```
{
    "login": "imukunya",
    "name": null,
    "company": null,
    "blog": "",
    "location": null,
    "email": null,
    "hireable": null,
    "bio": null,
    "twitter_username": null,
    "public_repos": 19,
    "public_gists": 0,
    "followers": 0,
    "following": 0,
    "created_at": "2020-04-28T07:14:15Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-11-06T04:20:24Z"
}
```

the javascript object

```
userProfile = {
    
    "login": "",
    "name": ,
    "company": ,
    "blog": "",
    "location":"" ,
    "email": "",
    "hireable": "",
    "bio": "",
    "twitter_username": "",
    "public_repos": 0,
    "public_gists": 0,
    "followers": 0,
    "following": 0,
    "created_at": "",
    "updated_at": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the spread operator.

```
userProfile = { ...userProfile, ...jsonResponse };
```